# Contraction map, inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Trying to show, that the map $$\phi: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2,\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}\frac{x^2+y^2}{100}\\\frac{xy^2+0.1}{100}\end{pmatrix}$$
is a contraction in some closed region around $0$. It looks like the $L_1$ metric is most promising. So, need to bound the following: $$\frac{1}{100}(|x_1^2+y_1^2-(x_2^2+y_2^2)|+|x_1y_1^2-x_2y_2^2|)$$The first part of the sum is straightforward (if we assume $|x_i|,|y_j|\leq0.5$), but I am stuck trying to bound $|x_1y_1^2-x_2y_2^2|$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:
$$
\begin{align}
\lvert x_1 y_1^2 - x_2 y_2^2 \rvert
&= \lvert x_1 y_1^2 - x_1 y_2^2 + x_1 y_2^2 - x_2 y_2^2 \rvert \\
&\le \lvert x_1 y_1^2 - x_1 y_2^2 \rvert + \lvert x_1 y_2^2 - x_2 y_2^2 \rvert \\
&= \lvert x_1 \rvert \lvert y_1 + y_2 \rvert \lvert y_1 - y_2 \rvert + y_2^2 \lvert x_1 - x_2 \rvert
\end{align}
$$
If we assume $\lvert x_i \rvert, \lvert y_i \rvert \le 1/2$, this implies that $$\lvert x_1 y_1^2 - x_2 y_2^2 \rvert \le \frac{1}{2}(\lvert x_1 - x_2 \rvert + \lvert y_1 - y_2 \rvert)$$